# Как сохранить состояние и расположение окна?

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть варианты сохранить состояние и расположение окна между сессиями?

Comment: Запихнуть в HKCU. Или в файл в профиле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно сохранить расположение и размер окна в настройках вашего приложения. Вот хорошая [статья](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15013/Windows-Forms-User-Settings-in-C)  на  C# для этого

Вы можете сохранить все, что угодно, в настройках приложения. В столбце `Type` в настройках вы можете перейти к любому типу .NET. `WindowState` находится в `System.Windows.Forms` и указан как `FormWindowState`. Существует также свойство `FormStartPosition`

Comment: Может я невнимательно прочитал ваше сообщение, но ещё надо состояние - как минимум развернутое окно от обычного надо отличать.